# Is it possible to do grouping within groups using extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have name, type and parent. I am able to group by 'type'. Is it possible to then group the resulting groups by 'parent' as well?

What I have tried in-order to group by 'type':

```
initComponent: function(){
    Ext.apply(this, {
        :
        :
        features: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
            groupHeaderTpl: '{columnName}: {name} <tpl if="children">({children.length} ' + this.items + ')</tpl>'
        })],
        forceFit: true,
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            groupField: 'type',
            model: 'model.props',
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'props'
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

This groups by 'type'. Now I need each resultant group to be grouped by 'parent' as well

Answer (score 1):

Not with standard ExtJS, a normal grid and groupers. These support only grouping by one property. But:

- Someone has done it for ExtJS 4 as a custom extension, which you can maybe adapt for your version of ExtJS: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?226739 https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?242633
- You can look into the standard [`TreePanel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html)/[`TreeStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.TreeStore.html) combination, in which you can build a hierarchy with arbitrary depth.